# How can I deny a file from being copied?

Tags: c#, permissions, access-control

I am working on an application that requires that some files are copied to a different folder. I use the following:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (FileInfo filesindires in dir.GetFiles())
{
  FileSecurity ds = filesindires.GetAccessControl();
  ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users", 
                   FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
  filesindires.SetAccessControl(ds);
}
```

With that method I deny the user from opening the file, but I would like to only prevent copying. How can I prevent that a file is copied while allowing the user to read it?

Comment: There's no real difference between opening a file to read it and opening a file to copy it - both are going to read the data. The only difference is that a copy operation tends to write the data back out to another file.

Comment: How to set permissions programmatically would be on topic here, but this question is how to choose permissions and that has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: If you can read the contents of the file you can copy it. Copy is simply creating a new file and duplicating the name, attributes, and contents of the file.

Comment: Lol! If it was possible noone would get so angry and crazy about piracy :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can read it, you can copy it.

Comment: To be pedantic, it should be "If you can read it, and you can create a file (anywhere), you can copy it."

Comment: @HaskellElephant: create a file, or open an outgoing network connection.  But yes, you're correct in spirit.

Comment: well you need to be able to open a file on any other machine connected to the network too :-).